# Filtering results from a DB with a Javascript that will make a DIV reload it's contents based on new arguments

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need to create a form with Checkboxes to filter results extracted from a MySQL table. Ideally, after clicking on specific checkboxes, a DIV will be reloaded running the appropriate PHP and PDO query to filter on the selected criteria.

This is my code so far, but it doesn't seem to work...

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#colors").change(function() {
            console.log("changed...");
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            console.log(data);
            $("#indexMain").load("index.php?data="+data)
        });
    })
</script>
<div class="colors">
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <?php
            $colors = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT color_base1 FROM item_descr ORDER BY color_base1");
            while ($colorBoxes = mysql_fetch_array($colors))
            {
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='color' value='".$colorBoxes[color_base1]."' /> ".$colorBoxes[color_base1]."<br />";
            }
        ?>
        <input type="submit" onclick="document.formName.submit();" />
    </form>
</div>
```

and I get the value in my div as follows:

```
$color = $_POST['color'];
if ($selectedColor == '') 
{
$items = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item_descr");
}
else 
{
$items = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item_descr ORDER BY $color");
}
```

Comment: 1st, as you use jquery, you would to use .submit() method instead of onclick

Comment: can you post the relevant code from index.php as well ?

Comment: helmus, i posted some more of the PHP... it's pretty simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Colors` is the name of your div, but I presume you want the on-change to be fired on your checkboxes, whose names are `color`, without an `s`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=checkbox][name=color]").change(function() {
        console.log("changed...");
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        console.log(data);
        $("#indexMain").load("index.php?data="+data)
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`#colors` is looking for an element with `id='colors'`. To find a class, your selector must start with a dot, like this `.color`. In your task, it may be reasonable to change `<div class="colors">` to `<div id="colors">`

I also didn't find an element with `id=indexMain` (`$("#indexMain")`).

Your code can be written like this:

```
<script>
$(function() { // short form of jQuery usage
    $(".color").change(function() {
        console.log("changed...");
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        console.log(data);
        $("#indexMain").load("index.php?data="+data)
    })
})
</script>

....

<select class="color"> // your options here
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option> 
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>

....

<div id="indexMain"></div>
```

But it uses a selectlist and I didn't test it - wrote the code in the editor.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work on my side...
The indexMain ID is there, it's the DIV's ID I want to reload...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean:

```
  $('input[name=color]').change(....
```